# Golang parsing template from third party lib

Tags: go, go-templates

I am writing a library which is parsing templates from its template package. When I am using it within a sample application its reading the template from its own directory but the code in libary is failing.

Here is the libary - https://github.com/bangarharshit/bigpipe-golang and I am facing issues with this line - https://github.com/bangarharshit/bigpipe-golang/blob/master/Application.go#L66

Copying code from lib -

```
templates, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/bigpipe.html")
if err != nil {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative soultion is to copy content from file into a variable and use template.parse instead of template.parsefiles